# How many VMs can I install on Windows Server 2016 standard?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016, licensing

With 1 Windows Server 2016 Standard (WS2016s) license (running Hyper-V) installed as host on a physical machine, how many VMs can I install on that machine? Is there a limit?

Could I install 10 Ubuntu Server as VMs or I am limited to 2 VMs per WS2016s license?

Comment: If your host only runs Hyper-V and nothing else, it does not count to your limit of two Windows Server instances and you can run up to two Windows server VMs and unlimited (limited by hardware only) other VMs (BSD, Linux...). If your host runs other roles as well (e.g. also the AD DC), then it does count towards your limit and you can only run a single Windows VM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard edition allows you to run two Windows Server VMs and unlimited # of other operating system VMs.

Answer (score 3):

A distinction needs to be made about what the licensing allows; Standard Edition licensing allows for 2 guest Windows OSE instances under a single Standard Edition license for the host.

**BUT**

You may stack multiple Standard Edition licenses on the host and run as many guest Windows OSE's as your license purchase allows. You could also license your guest Windows OSE's separately if you wanted to. The point is, you're not "limited" to only 2 guest Windows OSE's. The Standard Edition license allows you to license 2 guest Windows OSE's under the hosts license, but you could license and run as many guest Windows OSE's as your hardware supports and your license purchase allows (within the host and guest configuration maximums).

Comment: What is Windows OSE?

Comment: Operating System Environment, which is what Microsoft calls any running instance of Windows, whether physical or virtual.