# Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition Licensing for Virtual Machine on Hyper-V

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, licensing, limitations

I have windows server 2019 standard edition installed on my host machine and with 2 additional Windows server 2019 on Hyper-V virtual environment.  Now I want to install 2 more windows 10 client VMs (Hyper-V) on same host machine.  As I have read some of the Microsoft’s articles which say that there are only 2 VMs (Hyper-V) allowed in windows server standard edition, for adding more VMs (Hyper-V) Do I need to purchase another license for Hyper-V?

This are the following links which I follow

https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/C/E/7CED6910-C7B2-4196-8C55-208EE0B427E2/Windows_Server_2019_licensing_datasheet_EN_US.pdf

http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/Downloader.aspx?documenttype=PT&lang=English

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-pricing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to Purchase Server 2019..

Two things you should keep in your mind

```
 1. Number of servers (In case of Virtual machine)
 2. Number of cores in your server
```

For your case, Already you have 2 VM's. So **you have to purchase one more license.**

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply so for installing windows 10 so have to purchase windows 10 license right not the server license.

Comment: Are you going to prurchase Win 10 or Server OS

Comment: I already have install windows server 2019 standard edition in my host machine and with Hyper-V 2 windows server VMs are also install and wants to install 2 more VMs with windows 10

Comment: Okay, You have to purchase the Windows 10 License

Comment: It will be so kind for reference if you can share any documentation or any link for this scenario. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

> As I have read some of the Microsoft’s articles which say that there are only 2 VMs 
>   (Hyper-V) allowed in windows server standard edition,

You should read the license papers and possibly work on skills for that - it is a core competency in system administration these days. This is not "allowed", it is licensed. As in: to run another 2 servers you just need to add licenses that you pay for to the server (i.e. buy another server standard license and do not install the server). Keeping the paperwork organized is not that simple, but still doable quite easily if you keep organized.

OR you use them only for development - then MSDN covers that part to a VERY large degree, but all developers must be MSDN licensed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually I got confused after visited this https://serverfault.com/questions/935695/how-many-vms-can-i-install-on-windows-server-2016-standard stack exchange page.

Comment: Tom As I already mention in my question that I want to install 2 windows 10 virtual machine not another 2 server so for windows 10 I have to purchase windows 10 license or windows server standard license please check this link also    https://serverfault.com/questions/935695/how-many-vms-can-i-install-on-windows-server-2016-standard

Comment: Sorry, but we do NOT solve here your licensing issues which are solved by reading your license agreements and talking to a qualified vendor. The generic high level question is as much as you will get as the rest depends on your agreements in place.

Comment: Tom the reason for asking this question HERE because the same type of question are already answer one of the question link which I given in my previous comment and the answer given on that question was satisfactory. THANKS FOR THE HELP